# Fill the area with uniform spacing

Tags: algorithm, graphics

**User Requiremnts**

Inputs

1. User will give boundary points of the closed polygon P in which he wants to fill the area formed by polygon. Red Points P in the 
   Examples.
2. Space S in between the lines. Spacing S between the lines of Green points in Examples.

Output

The output will be a closed polygon points. Green G points in the Examples.

Can someone help me, i don't know which algorithm to use.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The example looks like it was created like this:

1. Create a field of hexagonally packed spots with the desired spacing;
2. Select the spots that are inside the red shape;
3. Imagine an edge with a random weight between each pair of adjacent spots (each spot will have up to 6 neighbours), and connect them into a minimum weight spanning tree using Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm (all that is googlable);
4. trace around the resulting tree